# По умолчанию не подключается библиотека android.support.design

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

При создании нового проекта не происходит автоматического подключение библиотеки android.support.designe. В результате чего в Android Studia возникают проблемы с рендерингом и невозможность в активити объявить и синить переменную типа TabLayout.
Приходится руками прописывать строку

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы эта библиотека подключалась автоматически?
Все компоненты студии, как и сама студия всегда обновлены до последней текущей версии.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: А откуда по вашему Android Studio должна знать, что вы хотите создать проект с данной подключенной либой. В этом и смысл, что проект пустой, а вы его наполняете. Просто после добавления поля compile выполните в Gradle "Sync Now"

Comment: Ну я и синхронизирую Gradle. Просто это ведь основная библиотека для материал дизайна. как бы логично если она будет сразу подключена. Это если я какую-нибудь кастомную библиотеку использовал, то там и вопроса не возникнет. А это гугловская библиотека.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить SDK и в Target SDK устанавливать версию Api 21 при создании проекта

Comment: Я ведь написал в описании, что SDK у меня всегда самая свежая версия. И в студии не указывается целевая SDK, при создании проекта. Там только указывается поддержка минимальной версии. А Target SDK уже меняется в Gradle после создания проекта. Я нашел проблему, дал ее в ответе к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался я почему так происходит. Если при создании проекта выбрать **Empty Activity** (***Пустая*** активность), то тогда библиотека **android.support.designe** не будет добавляться. Так как добавляется пустой проект, без всяких элементов материал дизайна. И библиотека получается не нужна. А если создать проект с хотя бы **Blank Activity**, то там уже будет подключена библиотека **android.support.designe**. Так как в **Blank Activity** по умолчанию добавлена плавающая кнопка (FAB) и ToolBar. А это уже элементы материал дизайна и логично, что библиотека элементов дизайна в проекте нужна.
Так что все оказалось очень просто)))